# Which phenomenon does a normal window glass shows?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, refraction, glass

As we are able see outside from our window glass since it shows refraction in day but what happens in night as in night we are unable to see out since it shows reflection in night and sometimes it shows [**both the phenomenon simultaneously**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhwPc.jpg). So my question is this that

> Which phenomenon does a window glass shows. Does it shows ***REFLECTION*** or shows ***REFRACTION*** or ***BOTH***?

Comment: For what downvote

Comment: Reflection and refraction aren't exclusive.  Some angles and light conditions make it easier to see reflection so that the window looks reflective during certain times or from certain angles.  Realistically most light is refracting through, and a bit is reflected.  That has to do with the surface properties.

Comment: Look at this illustration http://cdn.naturalpigments.com/education/images/light_refraction_1surface.gif

Comment: What do you think and why?

Comment: The phenomenon you are referring to is called partial reflection. A glass surface can reflect 0 to 16% of the light. In the daytime you can hardly notice 16% compared to the light outside. At night time even a small percentage of light would dominate. Here is a fun lecture from Richard Feynman that discusses this subject.https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Sccs-XG33EU